# Windows Store App with VS Express?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-store-apps

new to stackoverflow.

Want to code an app for Windows Store. But my VS2013 Express does not show a template for it. Any workarounds?

Appreciate your help!

Edit:

No code s part of the problem. In Microsofts tutorial the say: "pick the Windows Store template type" but there is no such template in VS Express.

So how to start coding without template?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986965.aspx

I have Win 8.1 installed along with VS2013 Express

Comment: Only trolls vote down without leaving a reason!

Comment: which OS is your system running on?

Comment: This is for technical questions only...there is no code, what you have tried, or anything. At least make an effort

Comment: I haven't tried but Karthik asks a valid question. If your machine isn't Windows 8 - you might not be able to code store apps. Otherwise - you can find sample apps in MSDN code gallery to see if they build on your machine if all you are missing is templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different versions of VS Express. (Web/Windows/Desktop)

Just download Visual Studio Express for Windows

Here's a link: http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-8

Comment: Thx I wasn't aware that my VS Express was just one of many.

Answer (score 0):

You might need a different version of Visual Studio Express 2013. Get Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/.